# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'db' is not defined

Tags: python, html, flask

'''
import db.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

```
app =Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'


class Question(db.model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     title  = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
     content = db.Column(db,Text, nullable=False)
     Date_Posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

     def __repr__(self):
         return 'Question' + str(self.id)


@app.route('/mainpage' , methods = ['GET'])
def mainpage():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route('/askdaiwik')
def ask():
    return render_template("ask.html" , ask = all_ask)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you are trying to use `SQLAlchemy` object as `db`. But you didn't create the object and hence `db` is undefined.

wrap your app with `SQLAlchemy` to create the object and assign the variable `db` to the instance.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

In db.py where you can store the code *db = SQLAlchemy()*.

Then import it in app.py. Now you can call *db.*

or just remove APP in *db=SQLAlchemy(app)*

Comment: **from db import " "** [link](https://pypi.org/project/db.py/)

Comment: @DaiwikKashyap have you installed db.py?